# Are there any GPS data pusher for Arduino?

Tags: tinygps

I plan to build a GPS logger for my car using a GPS device, an Arduino board and a SD Card. The plan is that the GPS device forwards the position to the Arduino which is responsible for storing the data on the SD card. However, I would like to regularly (say every hour) send my current position to a server at home.

For that you can use GPS pusher or puller, but I couldn't find any such devices on the Internet. Do these devices exist? What are my (other) options?

Comment: Not sure what goes into a data pusher but you could probably do it cheaper with a GSM module and server. - It wouldn't surprise me to find that in the device you're referring to.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but then I need a SIM and a dataplan imho.

Comment: So you want something besides the GSM shield?

Comment: If possible, yes.

Comment: How do you want to communicate with a server over the internet?

Comment: How do you expect to "push" gps data to a server? The only options you have available to you is 1) Internet (as suggested, bluetooth to phone and phone internet connection). 2) GSM module and either a) use data plan to push via internet, or b) use SMS to another device at the server location. Either way, you're going to need to transport the data over some medium for which you are going to have to have a "plan". As has been asked, what is the server connected to (I suspect the internet). There's no FREE magical internet like medium the Arduino can latch onto.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10039) out, it sounds almost exactly like what you need, plus it has OBD2 (CAN) access to log RPM, indicated speed, steering wheel angle, and whatever else your car exposes. You can get a GPS module from Sparkfun as well. Matter of fact, I'm using it in a [very similar project](https://bitbucket.org/nearwood/carduino), but development is paused until I upgrade to a Mega, since I've run out of RAM.

[image]

The shield comes with example code that's hacked together from other sources but it serves the demo purpose well.

As for pushing to a server--that'd be tougher. I would go the route of a Bluetooth shield and make a corresponding app for the phone that pushes the data.

Comment: Hi Nick and thanks. I see that you can use this for logging. Put what about pushing data to a remote host?

Comment: Easiest would probably be a Bluetooth shield and an app on an Android phone.

Comment: Yes, but then I still need a Internet connection.

Comment: How else are you going to access a server on the internet?